# getDay() won't work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I tried to build a simple code that returns the current day of the week but it doens't work for me at all:\

```
    $(document).ready(function () {


    var d = new Date();
    var n;
    var weekday;

    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";
    n = weekday[d.getDay()];

});
```

Does anybody know why it wouldn't work for me?
Thanks.

Comment: title of question isnt correct.

Comment: sorry for that. Changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var weekday = [];
```

Instead of

```
var weekday;
```

Comment: by the way, when i try to add it to the html code it does nothing.

$(n).appendTo($('#div1'));

Comment: Use it like `$("#div1").append(n)` to append or `$("#div1").html(n)` to print in `#div1`

Comment: i tried the first one and it works perfectly. but why is my code is wrong? thanks a lot.

Comment: Because `appendTo()` method inserts HTML elements at the end of the selected elements, but what you are trying to append is just an `integer`. To use that `wrap` `n` in `<span>` and then use `appendTo`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize your weekday array:

```
var weekday = new Array(7);
```

Comment: Why to write `new Array(7)`, `[]` works ! :)

Comment: Why not to be as clear as possible? There are different possible ways to do it...

Comment: Right.. You see I am a bit lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Change `var weekday` to `var weekday = []`

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hwa9apk/).

Answer (score 0):

Or define all the elements when you define the variable:

```
var weekday = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
```